# Encrypt and Decrypt JWT with algorithm RS512 in C#

Tags: c#, encryption, jwt

Could you please show me how to encrypt and decrypt data using JWT with RS512 C#.

I have private key of

```
private_modulus=8978158791.......(number only)
private_exponent=8487473636364..... (number only)
```

I have searched in Google but result is not clear and the they need private and public key, which I dont have or i dont know how to generate from above.

It has been done with Java and I try to do in C#.

Comment: Why RS512 and not PS512?

Answer (score 0):

I think you should not do this yourself. This is too error prone. You can use a ready made library by Microsoft itself, e.g.:

https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/

It can be used for generating/validation JWT and can use various algorithms as far as I remember.

Another option is an open source library if you like that more than MS:

https://github.com/jwt-dotnet/jwt

Comment: Thanks this really help. I cannot figure out how can i use the keys that provided. could you help pls..

Comment: This I am not 100% sure of how you do it. You should check a bit more on how to use this, perhaps you will need to join them in the key or create a certificate that is later used by the libraries. So I would start with checking the documentation on the library that you chose.

Comment: I have searched in Google. I could not find the way to use this.

Comment: Microsoft supports RS512, you can check it in their code here, e.g.: https://github.com/AzureAD/azure-activedirectory-identitymodel-extensions-for-dotnet/blob/master/src/System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt/JwtConstants.cs

Comment: I could not find out right away how to do it, so you might need to do some more investigations, but generally I think you will need to create a certificate from your raw RSA numbers and then use it as an algorithm in the JwtToken validation.

Comment: I successfully create JWT but when I pass to server and the server response invalid JWT. I  think I have not sign my JWT with provided key. I cannot find the way to sign with provided key.

Answer (score 0):

The private key is only needed to decrypt a JWE. For encryption, a public key has to be used.
If you have a private RSA key, you can easily convert it into a public key by removing all private primes and modulus (namely `d`, `p`,`q`, `dmp1`, `dmq1` and `iqmp`).

The RS512  is a signature algorithm, not an encryption one.
You should read about the [RFC7518, section 4.1](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7518#section-4.1) to find out a list of possible algorithms.
With an RSA key, you could use the `RSA1_5`, `RSA-OAEP` or `RSA-OAEP-256` algorithms.

Some libraries are listed [here](http://openid.net/developers/libraries/). Unfortunately, it seems there is no open-source library in C# that handle JWE.
However [such library exists in PHP](https://github.com/Spomky-Labs/jose) and as it is open source, a C# implementation could be created based on that work.

Comment: that give me more understanding. I have two keys one is modulus and exponent. so, what should I do? how can I sign JWT with these two private big integer? thanks.